# Computing values for a column in pandas using other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, euclidean-distance

I have a data-frame containing 3 columns: 'longitude', 'latitude', and 'country'. For some longitude and latitudes, the value in the country columns is 'unknown'. Here is an overview of the data-frame:

```
  longitude   latitude  country
-76.250000  83.083333  China
-76.166667  83.083333  unknown
-76.083333  83.083333  USA
-76.000000  83.083333  India
-75.916667  83.083333  unknown
-68.166667 -55.500000   unknown
-67.666667 -55.500000   UK
-68.166667 -55.583333   Chile
-68.083333 -55.583333   Canada
-67.500000 -55.666667   unknown
```

For the *unknown* countries, I want to calculate the **minimum euclidean distance** for longitudes and latitudes containing **a country name** and replace 'unknown' with that country name(minimum distance). Is there an efficient way to do that?

Comment: please include an output to help us understand your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not representative. The only country value you have is Chile. However, something like the following should work:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance

def euclidean(point, others):
    return others[distance.cdist(point[None,:-1].astype(float), others[:,:-1].astype(float)).argmin(),2]

unknown = df[df["country"].eq("unknown")]
known = df[df["country"].ne("unknown")]

matches = unknown.apply(lambda row: scipy_euclidean(row.to_numpy(), known.to_numpy()), axis=1)
df["country"] = df["country"].where(df["country"].ne("unknown"), matches)

>>> df
   longitude   latitude country
0 -76.250000  83.083333   China
1 -76.166667  83.083333   China
2 -76.083333  83.083333     USA
3 -76.000000  83.083333   India
4 -75.916667  83.083333   India
5 -68.166667 -55.500000   Chile
6 -67.666667 -55.500000      UK
7 -68.166667 -55.583333   Chile
8 -68.083333 -55.583333  Canada
9 -67.500000 -55.666667      UK
```

###### Performance:

```
big_df = pd.concat([df]*1000)
unknown = big_df[big_df["country"].eq("unknown")]
known = big_df[big_df["country"].ne("unknown")]

>>> %timeit unknown.apply(lambda row: euclidean(row.to_numpy(), known.to_numpy()), axis=1)
847 µs ± 26.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: hey, I edited the question. I tried running this code but as my data-frame is huge, it is taking too long to execute. I was thinking to separate the dataframe into two( one containing unknown, and the other containing other countries) and then try to calculate the distances but even that is computationally very heavy.

Comment: @Rifly - I edited my answer to split the dataframe and apply the function. I've also used `scipy` and am working with the frames underlying numpy array which should be faster - but it still depends on your dataset size.

Comment: much appreciated! I think with new edit the code does not run because of type conversion from float to string. can you check

Comment: I don't have any such errors. You could try `row.to_numpy().astype(float), known.to_numpy().astype(float)` but otherwise post a better sample that causes the error.